# Why should one want the password to expire in Salesforce?

Tags: security, user, user-management, passwords

Why should one want the password to expire in Salesforce? Is it the same as a temporary account? Because if the password invalidates after some time that means the user won`t be able to login and hence won`t be able to use the account.

[image]

Comment: It all depends on the "Corporate Security Policy". Also, setting this option does not disable the account access, but it asks User to change password when they login using their old password, and that it has expired. Very similar to any other application.

Comment: It's like added-extra-security feature for the user account. It explicitly reminds the user to change the password regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad and very opinion based, but some pointers as below can help.

> Why should one want the password to expire in Salesforce?

This is a debatable topic, but it all depends on the "Corporate Security Policy". Different companies have different security policy which is required either for compliance reasons or are their home grown policies. But in any of the cases, the most important thing is to provide a more secured cover to their data/assets.

If you see details on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_policy) on this topic, you will find more on this. But refer to the below excerpt:

> if an unauthorized person acquires a password and uses it without being detected, that person may have access for an indefinite period.

One of a very strong reasons, why there should be a limit to the duration of a password.

In general, a Password Policy always helps to protect your data from unauthorized access and that frequently revisiting your password always is a good practice.

There are lots of resources available where you can find more on how to set a good password policy.

Also setting this option does not lock out User if the password expires, rather Salesforce will force the User to reset their password once they login with their old password and that it has expired.

Comment: I got curious about the following. What will happen if an unauthorized person gets first to the password expiration and updates password for himself. Lol, will it prevent real users from accessing the org or are there means like email verification in the process of setting up a new password after expiration in Salesforce?